# sublime text 2 emmet plugin issues

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I just got the message of the new released plugin from Emmet in sublime text 2.

I tried it out but i still get the same issue as before meaning I can't make the wrapping action work. None of the demos in the following link are working for me : http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

For instance in the first demo it says "Wrap with Abbreviation" using Shift+Ctrl+A shortcut, and it's supposed to open a dialog box in which you can input your abreviation code wrapping. But it doesn't work. Instead, this shortcut selects the word where i trigger it and if i keep doing so it adds the nearby words or tags, but still no dialog box.

Does anybody has the same issue? Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those shortcuts in docs are for demo boxes only. Your plugin may have different shortcuts.

In Sublime Text: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions

Comment: Hi Sergey and thank you to answer me. Ok i didn't know that, i thought the docs shortcuts were actually available :). So i tried to check your link and still some won't work. For example the wrapping with abbreviation one interest me but i can't make it work. Maybe I should tell you that i installed it through ST2, I didn't download the masters from github. Could that be it?

Comment: You should fill an issue if something doesn’t work for you: http://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues